# Ebean: How to use wildcard for field names with RawSqlBuilder?

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.3

There's sample method:

```
private static List<Foo> getFoos() {
    Query<Foo> query = Ebean.find(Foo.class);
    query.setRawSql(
            RawSqlBuilder
                    .parse("SELECT * FROM foo")
                    .create()
    );

    return query.findList();
}
```

Unfortunately it throws an exception:

> [PersistenceException: Property [*] not found on models.Foo]

Of course it fine works if I specify fields in the SQL like:

```
.parse("SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM foo")
```

anyway I would prefer to do not it manually as later Ebean executes additional queries for fetching properties not in list, how can I use `*` wildcard for model's field names in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `unparsed` instead

```
RawSqlBuilder
    .unparsed("SELECT * FROM SomeTable")
    .columnMapping("id", "id")
    .create();
```

Note that you need to specify at least one column mapping, or Ebean will complain with something like this

```
Query threw SQLException: Column Index out of range, 0 < 1
```

Comment: Almost... unfortunately it doesn't resolve the problem finally, if given column isn't mapped by `columnMapping("foo", "foo")` Ebean performs auto-fetch... that would be real _performance-killer_ on large data sets.